# PHP Header Function Not Working Well

Tags: php

I have one file "djakhiltalreja_video.php" and another file "mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php".i just want to redirect to this link http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php , current page :- djakhiltalreja_video.php .
but redirected url is http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php .
why double occurence of mobile_ ???

```
<?php
$pagename = "mobile_".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
header('Location: http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/'.$pagename);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Because of you are add `mobile_` prefix in your `$pagename`.

Answer (score 1):

Note : Remove mobile prefix from your page-name. I think it's covered in to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Please check below solution for your problem.

**Solution :**

```
$pagename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$url = "http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/".$pagename;

if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
} else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        exit;
}
```

This simple code will do the trick for you. It will check if headers are not sent, then it will call the PHP’s header function to redirect. But if the headers are sent, it will use Javascript to redirect to the URL you want.

Comment: Its header function working fine but problem with `mobile_` prefix in your `$pagename`.

Comment: still not working :( , you can try this (http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/djakhiltalreja_video.php)

Comment: @hardiksolanki , okk if i remove "mobile_" , then what should i do to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: @RobinRbn what is your purpose to used `mobile_` in your `$pagename` variable?

Comment: @RobinRbn, Have you remove mobile prefix from your page name & tried that ? Also please `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` check this

Comment: @hardiksolanki , because i want to redirect to mobile site when user click this link -> http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/djakhiltalreja_video.php , then user must be redirected to http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php but real output is http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php

Comment: @RobinRbn Then change your mobile file name to `djakhiltalreja_video_mobile.php` or anything.

Comment: please `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` check this. Give me output of this.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia , output is /djakhiltalreja_video.php

Comment: @RobinRbn, Remove `/` then append it with mobile prefix.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia , i already use basename function to do this , but problem is this >>>  i want to redirect to mobile site when user click this link -> akhil.djmusicweb.com/djakhiltalreja_video.php , then user must be redirected to akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php but real output is akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php

Comment: Check below sample example : 
`$serverUrl = "/djakhiltalreja_video.php";
$serverUrl = ltrim($serverUrl, '/');

$pagename = "mobile_".$serverUrl;`

Comment: @RobinRbn, Check it without basename so from your server url you got `/` so you need to trim that from your url & then check it with mobile prefix.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia , yes for that reason i used basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) , it trim '/' , but output is again mobile_mobile_..... :(

Comment: @RobinRbn, Then change your mobile file name & then check it with that name.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia , how could i keep two same file name in one directory , and i don't want to make another folder and insert all obile webpages

Comment: @RobinRbn When I run your what you have provided, it prepends as you are intending and forwards as you are intending it to. That doesn't really help you but since it doesn't return the same results as what you are describing, I can not put in any input more than to say what you have provided works for me.

Comment: @RobinRbn Why can't you just `include('mobile.code.php'); exit;` the code instead of try and redirect it since that is not working?

Comment: @Rasclatt , because their is more than 15 pages , and i dont want to this in all file , i have a common file and this common file in incuded in all remaining files , and when user click http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/djakhiltalreja_video.php then it redirect to http://akhil.djmusicweb.com/mobile_djakhiltalreja_video.php , but this is not happening :(